# Mysql Data Only Pulling Last Result Into Json Array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm pulling multiple rows from a table and formatting them to this standard: 3 Swords, 5 Daggers, etc.

Well When I try to put that data into a json Array, It's only pulling the last result as this `[{"weapons":"You Used: 3 Rusty Dagger's, "}]` Which it should say: `[{"weapons":"You Used: 3 Rusty Dagger's, 2 Swords"}]`

Here's The Query I'm currently using, Which will show perfectly inside of the while loop:

```
$get_weapons = mysql_query("SELECT 
   O.player_id,
   O.item_id,
   O.name,
   O.attack,
   O.defense,
   O.type,
   O.owned,
   (SELECT 
      sum(owned) FROM items_owned 
    WHERE owned <= O.owned AND player_id=$id) 'RunningTotal' 
FROM items_owned O
HAVING RunningTotal <= $mob_avail 
ORDER BY attack DESC");
// Get Weapon Info
while($weapon = mysql_fetch_array($get_weapons)){
    $weapon_id = $weapon['item_id'];
    $weapon_name = $weapon['name'];
    $weapon_attack = $weapon['attack'];
    $weapon_defense = $weapon['defense'];
    $weapon_owned = $weapon['owned'];
    // Formatting Weapons Message
    $weapon_message = 'You Used: '.$weapon_owned.' '.$weapon_name.'\'s, ';
}
$data[] = array('weapons'=>$weapon_message);
echo json_encode($data);
```

I understand that the `$data` array is outside of the while loop, But I'm only needing a total of one arrays, so I'm kind of stuck on what to do to fix this issue. Any help would be awesome

Comment: Your while loop overwrites the variables inside on each loop. You should store them in an array rather than a static variable. E.g  $weapon_id [$i] = $weapon ['item_id']; then at the end of the while loop put $i++; then access the array after the while loop.

Comment: You need to array_push the weapons into an array inside your while loop. Then count the occurences in the array. Only after that you can set you message, after your while loop.

Comment: @Matt I'm some what confused by what you mean, And all of a sudden The query isn't working at all, But In the database I typed the same Query and it worked inside of the database, But in the PHP file it's no longer wanting to output any data. Could their be any reasons?

Comment: @Matt I'm now getting `[{"weapons":null}]`

Comment: Also In the error log I'm getting: `PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/carlos1/public_html/attack.php on line 26`

Comment: @CarlosMoore can you paste the amended code into pastebin / update this post?

Comment: Also your $weapon_message is an array now so you'll have to loop through it and add it to data

Answer (score 0):

You should add one static variable before append the results into the message.

Here is the reference answer:

```
 $get_weapons = mysql_query("SELECT O.player_id, O.item_id, O.name, O.attack, O.defense, O.type, O.owned, (
        SELECT sum(owned) FROM items_owned WHERE owned <= O.owned AND player_id=$id) 'RunningTotal' FROM items_owned O HAVING RunningTotal <= $mob_avail ORDER BY attack DESC");
        // Initialize the message
        $weapon_message = 'You Used: ';
        // Get Weapon Info
        while($weapon = mysql_fetch_array($get_weapons)){
            $weapon_id = $weapon['item_id'];
            $weapon_name = $weapon['name'];
            $weapon_attack = $weapon['attack'];
            $weapon_defense = $weapon['defense'];
            $weapon_owned = $weapon['owned'];
            // Formatting Weapons Message
            $weapon_message = $weapon_message.$weapon_owned.' '.$weapon_name.'\'s, ';
        }
        $data[] = array('weapons'=>$weapon_message);
        echo json_encode($data);
```